# Is it possible to express the inverse of a polynomial as a series?

Tags: polynomials, power-series, binomial-theorem

Is it possible to express the multiplicative inverse of a polynomial in descending powers of n i.e.
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^{n-2k}\right]^2} \end{equation}
 as a series using binomial theorem or any other tool?

additional notes: $ a_0 \neq 0 $ and the polynomial has real and distinct roots.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it can be done. For nice simple polynomials, partial fractions are a useful tool.

Comment: i need it for the general case that i descibe here. i need to approximate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the inversion for formal power series: If you have a power series
$$
\sum_i c_i x^i
$$ and want to write its inverse as
$$
\sum_i b_i x^i = \frac{1}{\sum_i c_i x^i}
$$
you see that it has to hold
$$
\sum_i b_i x^i \sum_i c_ix^i \equiv 1.
$$
Using the Cauchy product on the left gives some
$$
\sum_i d_i x^i\equiv 1
$$
 and comparing of the coefficients (i.e. noting that $d_0 = 1$, $d_i=0$ for $i\geq 1$) a gives equations for the $b_i$. Note that there is no guarantee that the series $\sum_i b_i x^i$ has positive radius of convergence…

Comment: i had this in mind but because of the convergence didn 't try it. since we are two now, i will !

Comment: As long as $c_0$ is nonzero, I do believe the radius of convergence is guaranteed to be positive when the input is polynomial.  And if $c_0=0$ then the above will fail, though it can easily be fixed by allowing some negative exponents.